# Make @media max-width behave the same as $(window).width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

While working on a website I encountered a major frustrating, yet logical problem.

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdgKB/).

**Important CSS**:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#wrapper {
    padding: 1em;
}

img {border: 4px solid blue;}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img {border: 0 none;}
}
```

**Important jQuery**:

```
function imgSize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 481) {
        $("img").css({
            "position": "relative",
                "width": $(window).width(),
                "max-width": "none",
                "left": "-1em",
                "float": "none"
        });
    } else {
        $("img").attr("style", "");
    }
}
imgSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    imgSize();
});
```

Try making the result window smaller than 481px and bigger again. Basic functionality explained: When the window is smaller than 481px in width, the image will be forced a width that's larger than its parent and equal to the window width. You cannot do this with CSS. (If you can, please tell me!) This should give a nice view on mobile devices. To further "beautify" the image, the original border is removed when the screen is between zero and 480px, this is done by media queries.

All of this works great, until ... **a wild scrollbar appears**! What happens is that jQuery only takes the "window" into account, whereas the media query also counts the pixels generated by the width of the scrollbar.

Actually, this is quite logical. `$(*window*).width()` and `@media *screen*` but it's super frustrating. What is the best way to deal with this issue? Write a custom function in jQuery that comes down to "if scrollbar: add x pixels to the "if window width"-function" in which *x* is the width of the scrollbar in a specific operating system. Or should we try to bypass this with CSS, or just not using jQuery and CSS interchangeably?

I am not focusing on this issue alone, but on the difference between `$(window).width()` and `media queries` in general. In my case, I could actually add `border: 0 none` to the jQuery and that's that. But unfortunately that's not always possible. Preferably without the use of a plugin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) could fix this. It lets you bind JS functions to "media query match and unmatch events".

Using this library you could fire `imgSize();` when the media query takes effect, this then eliminates the need for the `$(window).width()` check using jQuery inside `imgSize();`.

If you don't want to use a plugin, [you could do it this way](http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript) (copied code, untested) :

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)");

mql.addListener(handleMediaChange);
handleMediaChange(mql);

var handleMediaChange = function (mediaQueryList) {
    if (mediaQueryList.matches) {
        // The browser window is at least 480px wide
    }
    else {
        // The browser window is less than 480px wide
    }
}
```

I think in any case its a good idea to bind your function to a media query match event instead of trying to align two different ways of getting the screen width. I'm quite sure the width of the scrollbar isn't the same across browsers, so calculating with it wouldn't be a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Nice find. I don't like using additional plugins though. Will mention that in the post.

Comment: In that case you should have a look here: http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript, it shows you how to do the same thing but directly without those additional plugins.

Comment: + 1. Waiting for other answers. :)